# Como restringir determinadas extensões de arquivos e salvar no banco de dados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, imagem

Preciso fazer um upload de imagens para o meu banco de dados e usarei o tipo de dados como Bytes no banco SQL Server.

Como garanto que realmente seria uma imagem que estará passando para ele? Quero deixar liberado apenas para arquivos .jpeg e .png. É possível fazer isto?

Como realizo a integração do `input` HTML para pegar o arquivo via C#?

Comment: Possivelmente isso daí é a partir do cabeçalho do arquivo.
Mas você tem duas dúvidas?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar sim são duas dúvidas baseadas no mesmo problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que o browser liste apenas arquivos de imagens você pode fazer isso:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/jpg, image/png">
```

Porém, você precisará fazer também uma validação no Controller, supondo que a assinatura do seu método seja algo parecido com o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string extensao = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    string[] extensoesValidas = new string[] { "jpg", "png" };

    if (!extensoesValidas.Contains(extensao))
        new HttpException(string.Format("Extensão de arquivo *.{0} não suportada", extensao));

    var img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);

    //código para salvar a imagem no banco
}
```

Ainda é possível testar o *ContentType* para garantir maior eficiência:

```
string[] contentTypes = new string[] { "image/jpg", "image/png" };
if (!contentTypes.Contains(file.ContentType))
{
    //código para mensagem de erro
}
```

Lista de [ContentTypes](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm) existentes.

Comment: Ótimo! Valeu! Será de grande ajuda!

Comment: eu fiz uma edição, com um método nativo para conseguir a extensão do arquivo: `Path.GetExtension()`