# É possivel validar a importação de um arquivo excel com regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou a importar um arquivo excel utilizando asp.net e validar para ver se ele é realmente um excel ou não. Não quero usar `if` e `else`, então estou tentando fazer isso através de *annotations*.

Minha ideia principal agora é utilizar *regular expressions*, achei algumas na internet para validar excel, tentei todas mas sempre elas me retornam a mensagem dizendo que o arquivo não é excel, mesmo quando ele é (Todos os tipos de arquivos que eu posto estão sendo invalidados).

Alguém sabe se realmente é possivel fazer essa validação no asp.net com essas reg. expressions?

Segue o código dá model que estou tentando validar:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^ (?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(xls|xlsx)$
        ", ErrorMessage = "O arquivo selecionado precisa ser um excel")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Arquivo Excel")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ArquivoExcel { get; set; }
```

Comment: Olá @joaoigor seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Dê uma olhada nesse link aqui mesmo do SOpt http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5115/como-restringir-determinadas-extens%C3%B5es-de-arquivos-e-salvar-no-banco-de-dados , creio eu que esteja relacionado com o que você está querendo.

Comment: Tenha em atenção que o facto do ficheiro ter a extensão do Excel, não significa que seja um arquivo Excel valido. Da mesma forma, pode ter um arquivo Excel com uma extensão diferente (exemplo, `.xyz`) e continua a ser um arquivo Excel valido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um atributo de validação de arquivo:

```
public class ArquivoExcelAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        if (extension != ".xls" || extension != ".xlsx") return false;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
[ArquivoExcel(ErrorMessage = "Apenas arquivos do Excel são aceitos.")]
[Display(Name = "Arquivo Excel")]
public HttpPostedFileBase ArquivoExcel { get; set; }
```

Comment: Essa classe ArquivoExcelAttribute vai ser criada dentro da minha model? caso sim, esse Path.GetExtension não vai funcionar, pois o path só existe no controller.

Comment: Não, você cria um diretório `Attributes` na sua solução e implementa lá uma classe nova. `Path.GetExtension` pode existir nessa classe sim.